# how pass table view data?

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm passing data from a module to my detailView but how to I pass this data along to my edit view?

[image]

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if let identifier = segue.identifier{
        switch identifier {
            case "edit view":
                let editTableVC = segue.destinationViewController as! EditTableViewController
                if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell){
                    editTableVC.product = productAtIndexPath(indexPath)
                }
            case "detail view":
                let detailTableVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailTableViewController
                if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell){
                    detailTableVC.product = productAtIndexPath(indexPath)
                }

            default: break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: my edit table is empty

Comment: I belive the table cell data is passed to the detail view but the data is not passed to the edit view do to the fact that the table cell that is connected to the segue that leads to the edit view does not contain any data, but how can i store this data in that table cell?

Comment: Is navigation hapening?

Comment: yes the navigation is good, but due to the fact that the edit table only connected to the table cell "make a tribute" and that dont contain any data so there is nothing to send. is there anyway I can make the detailTableVC variable indexPath global or avalible from edit view?